# Is BoxClient thread-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, box-api

Are com.box.boxjavalibv2.BoxClient and the managers it returns (FoldersManager, CommentsManager, et cetera) thread-safe?

I know the JavaDoc says:

> All methods in this class are executed in the invoking thread, and
>   therefore are NOT safe to execute in the UI thread of your
>   application. You should only use this class if you already have worker
>   threads or AsyncTasks that you want to incorporate the Box API into.

I want to know if multiple worker threads can share a single BoxClient object.

Update: After poking around the code and testing it being shared by 15 threads in a multiprocessor environment, it does seem to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

It is thread safe.
The java doc here basically says you don't want to invoke it in your UI thread. In normal application, it makes your UI thread frozen while network calls is executing. In android application, it's going to cause crash because android(newer os versions) forbids executing network calls in UI thread.

Comment: Jian is the author of the Java Box SDK, so his answer is authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

"All methods in this class are executed in the invoking thread, and therefore are NOT safe to execute in the UI thread of your application. You should only use this class if you already have worker threads or AsyncTasks that you want to incorporate the Box API into."

I did just a google search, If it is wrong, sorry

https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/blob/master/BoxJavaLibraryV2/src/com/box/boxjavalibv2/BoxClient.java

Comment: I read that in the JavaDoc. I want to know if I can share a single BoxClient object across multiple worker threads?

Comment: I did just google search, I don't know even what is BoxClient :)